# Customize \verb!...! output in beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I would like to change my verbatim throughout a `beamer` presentation in the preamble.

Actually I would like to have it more or less like on slide no. 9 [here](http://www.slideshare.net/stephanepechard/latex-for-beginners).

[image]

I am using verbatim usually with `\verb!...!` rather than the environment because for longer codes I use `listings`. As far as I can tell the `fancyvrb` only allows customization in packages.

Comment: Is your question about the blue part? Because the rest is, as far as I can tell, simply `\verb` output.

Comment: No its about the black. The verbatim output is much smaller than the rest of the text. How do you for instance manage to do that? What is the command so to change the size and perhaps font of all \verb!...! elements in your document.

Comment: You can study [the sources](https://gitorious.org/latex-for-beginners/latex-for-beginners/blame/4705ea907be5a592b8e95dd52cadd23373177a96:LaTeXForBeginners.tex)

Answer (score 10):

To change the font for the standard `\verb` command (and `verbatim` environment) you can redefine `\verbatim@font` as I did in my example code below; however, since you are already using the `listings` package, you can use `\lstinline` for short texts and the `lstlisting` environment for longer verbatim texts and use `\lstset` to give the same appearance to both short and long texts.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\footnotesize\ttfamily}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red!60!black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lstinline{amsmath}, \lstinline{amssymb} and \lstinline{amsthm} for mathematics.
\item \lstinline{geometry} for easy management of document margins.
\item  \verb+graphicx+ for managing external images.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]